# Why is the control not coming back to caller on first await

Tags: c#, async-await

I am not sure my understanding of Await is right. The sequence of output is different from what I expected.

Here is the calling code.

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var levelOne = new LevelOne();
        levelOne.Work();
        Console.WriteLine("Waiting for answer...");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

This is LevelOne class

```
public class LevelOne
{
    public async void Work()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Starting work.");
        await LevelTwo.SomeRandomWork();
        Console.WriteLine("Work done.");
    }
}
```

And finally this is LevelTwo class

```
public class LevelTwo
{
    public static async Task SomeRandomWork()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        Console.WriteLine("Here I am");
        var someRandomNumber = await KillTime();
        Console.WriteLine("Answer " + someRandomNumber);
        someRandomNumber = await KillTime();
        Console.WriteLine("Answer again: " + someRandomNumber);
    }

    private static async Task<long> KillTime()
    {
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5000));
        Random random = new Random();
        return random.Next(100000, 900000);
    }
}
```

What I see is

```
Starting work.
Here I am
Waiting for answer...
Answer 352100
Answer again: 453356
Work done.
```

Here is the output I expect.

```
Starting work.
Waiting for answer...
Here I am
Answer 141710
Answer again: 530010
Work done.
```

Shouldn't the control come back to caller code after the await in LevelOne's Work method is hit? The control does not come back till the await in the LevelTwo's is hit.

Comment: @PetSerAl That actually makes sense now. I did not see this comment. Put it in as an answer. Not sure if this is somehow in sync with what had been pointed out in answer.

Comment: Can the downvoter please let me know the reason? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are using `Thread.Sleep` instead of `await Task.Delay(...)` inside `SomeRandomWork()`. That is why the code up to the first `await` inside `SomeRandomWork()` is executed *synchronously* before the `await` inside `Work()` yields control:

```
public static async Task SomeRandomWork() {
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    Console.WriteLine("Here I am");
    var someRandomNumber = await KillTime();
    Console.WriteLine("Answer " + someRandomNumber);
    someRandomNumber = await KillTime();
    Console.WriteLine("Answer again: " + someRandomNumber);
}
```

Once you make the switch, the output changes to what you expected:

```
Starting work.
Waiting for answer...
Here I am
Answer 598694
Answer again: 353771
Work done.
```

Comment: Key is, everything up to the first `await` inside `SomeRandomWork()` is executed _synchronously_ before the `await` in `Work()` (the "caller code") yields control.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Why the synchronous execution went till `await` in `SomeRandomWork` going past the `await` in `Work()`? I am failing to understand that.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Even when the `Thread.Sleep` is removed the output is same. I assumed that the control will return back to the caller when the first await (in the `Work`) is encountered provided the operation is not completed.

Comment: @NotAgain `Thread.Sleep` shouldn't be removed, it should be replaced with `Task.Delay` to let the caller squeeze in its `"Waiting for answer..."` before `"Here I am"` is printed. I ran this locally several times, and copied the output of a running program into the answer.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Please see the comment by PetSerAl. I think it makes sense.